# How to go to the previous page using the button on the smartphone in Flutter WebView?

Tags: flutter, webview

I implemented a floatingActionButton to move to the previous page as shown in the code below.

Is it possible to use the back button on a smartphone to move to the previous page without using floatingActionButton?

This is the source code I implemented.

[image]

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

final uri = Uri.parse('https://google.com');

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  WebViewController controller = WebViewController()
    ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
    ..setNavigationDelegate(NavigationDelegate(
      onPageFinished: (String url){
        print(url);
      }
    ))
    ..loadRequest(uri);

  HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      floatingActionButton: Container(
        height: 40.0,
        width: 40.0,
        child: FittedBox(
        child: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        onPressed: () => controller?.goBack(),
        backgroundColor:  Colors.grey.shade200,
      ),
      ),
      ),

      body: SafeArea(
        child : WebViewWidget(
        controller: controller,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manage back key press in Flutter, either as a drag gesture or with the -> button in your img :

***PopScope***

```
PopScope(
  canPop: /* BOOL VALUE THAT CHECK IF ITS OK TO CLOSE APP OR NOT , YOU MAY PASS FALSE:)*/ false ,
  onPopInvoked: (didPop) {
    //FUNCTION THAT CALL WHEN EVER THE BACK CLICKED :) 
    controller?.goBack();
  },
  child: Scaffold(
  
    floatingActionButton: Container(
      height: 40.0,
      width: 40.0,
      child: FittedBox(
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () => controller?.goBack(),
          backgroundColor:  Colors.grey.shade200,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  
    body: SafeArea(
      child : WebViewWidget(
        controller: controller,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

*deprecated*! **WillPopScope** also may Works

> 'WillPopScope' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use PopScope instead. This feature was deprecated after v3.12.0-1.0.pre. ([Documentation](https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages?utm_source=dartdev&utm_medium=redir&utm_id=diagcode&utm_content=deprecated_member_use#deprecated_member_use))

I hope it help you :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is the answer I wanted.